# How to fix `POM file is invalid` when using multyply `exclude`?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, pom.xml, maven-plugin

```
dependencies {
...
api ("com.jakewharton:butterknife:${rootProject.ext.butterKnifeVersion}"){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-compat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
...
}
```

publishing looks like this:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        bintrayMavenPublication(MavenPublication) {
            groupId theGroupId
            artifactId theArtifactId
            version theVersion

            artifact androidJavadocsJar
            artifact androidSourcesJar
            artifact bundleRelease

            pom.withXml {
                final dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                ext.addDependency = { Dependency dep, String scope ->
                    final dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', dep.group)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', dep.group == theGroupId ? dep.name.substring(9) : dep.name)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('version', dep.version)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('scope', scope)

                    if (!dep.transitive) {
                        final exclusionNode = dependencyNode.appendNode('exclusions').appendNode('exclusion')
                        exclusionNode.appendNode('groupId', '*')
                        exclusionNode.appendNode('artifactId', '*')
                    } else if (!dep.properties.excludeRules.empty) {
                        final exclusionNode = dependencyNode.appendNode('exclusions').appendNode('exclusion')
                        dep.properties.excludeRules.each { ExcludeRule rule ->
                            exclusionNode.appendNode('groupId', rule.group ?: '*')
                            exclusionNode.appendNode('artifactId', rule.module ?: '*')
                        }
                    }
                }

                configurations.api.getAllDependencies().each { dep -> addDependency(dep, "compile") }
                configurations.implementation.getAllDependencies().each { dep -> addDependency(dep, "runtime") }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In result pom file has this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>library-example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jakewharton</groupId>
      <artifactId>butterknife</artifactId>
      <version>8.8.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
          <artifactId>support-annotations</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
          <artifactId>support-compat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

As you can see now in `<exclusion>` tag there are two `<artifactId>` and two `<groupId>`. How to fix it and split it to two separate tags `<exclusion>`?

The error is :

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>
>   Execution failed for task ':mvpr:publishBintrayMavenPublicationPublicationToMavenCustomRepository'.
>
>   > Failed to publish publication 'bintrayMavenPublication' to repository 'mavenCustom'
>   >     Invalid publication 'bintrayMavenPublication': POM file is invalid. Check any modifications you have made to the POM file.
>
>   - Try:
>       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by:

```
...
} else if (!dep.properties.excludeRules.empty) {
                        // Otherwise add specified exclude rules
                        final exclusionsNode = dependencyNode.appendNode('exclusions')
                        dep.properties.excludeRules.each { ExcludeRule rule ->
                            def exclusion = exclusionsNode.appendNode('exclusion')
                            exclusion.appendNode('groupId', rule.group ?: '*')
                            exclusion.appendNode('artifactId', rule.module ?: '*')
                        }
                    }
...
```

Comment: Having the exact same issue even after already having this elseif segment... Did you have a way to debug this further? I also have 2 excludes for one dependency but this excludeRules are already in place and are not helping.